# why the tooltip does not show up always:

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery tooltip to show the tooltip box when the user hovers over some specific words. Text which contains those words is inside a box which getting the data using an ajax call. The data inside the box can change if the user selects a new option from a dropdown. 
The problem is when the data change using a new selection from the dropdown, the tooltip sometimes show up and sometimes not. I inspected the element each time and there is no difference time by time. If I refresh the page when the tooltip does show up, it is going to be fixed and show the tooltip. What should I do to fixed this problem without refresh?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have difficulties understanding the question. Here's what I understand: You have some sort of `contenteditable` box in which you edit text. Each individual word of that text can display a tooltip. The content of that tooltip is fetched from the server via AJAX. Did I understand this correctly?

Comment: Without seeing any code, my only suggestion would be to make sure you're using the latest released versions of jQuery and jQuery UI.

Comment: I have a library app. In a page the user can search for a book. when the book information shows up (using ajax) one of the data is the 'bookType' which has a label as 'Type'. This label need to have a tooltip which explains about the type(for example if it is a historical book tooltip explains about the historical book type). when the book changes then the type may change and the tooltip will change. but sometimes I need to refresh the page to see the tooltip.

Comment: My guess is: you create the tooltip when the page is loaded, but not after you get the data using AJAX. Without code, that's as far as I can help.

Comment: Thanks @Nolonar. I just needed to call my tips function when the ajax call runs.